# About Purely Inseparable Extension

Tags: galois-theory

An element $a \in E$ is called purely inseparable over $F$ if $a^{p^d}\in F$.

Now I have the following theorem. TFAE

1. Every element of $E$ is purely inseparable.
2. $[E:K]_s=1$
3. minimal polynomial of any element of $E$ is of the form $x^{p^d}-a\in K[x]$.
4. $E=K(a_1, a_2, a_3 \dots a_n)$ and each $a_i$ is purely inseparable.

While proving $(2)\Rightarrow (3)$, I started with $[E:K]_s=1$, that is the number of $F$-embeddings of $F \to \overline{F}$ is $1$. Thus the number of distinct roots of $m_K(a)=1$ in $\overline{F}$ is only $1$. Thus $a$ is the only root of $bm_K(a)$ and thus $m_K(a)=(x-a)^n$ for some $ n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now I am wondering why $n=p^d$ why it cannot be any other integer? Why $n$ must be a power of prime.
I am stuck here and looking for explainations to proceed further.

Comment: What is $p$, what is $d$? What are the characteristics of $F,E$, what do we know about $E/F$, ...

Comment: $p$ is the char of the field $E,F$ otherwise over zero char every polynomial is separable. $d$ is an integer and $E/F$ is finite.

Comment: Your definition of "purely inseparable" is incomplete/incorrect. First, "Purely inseparable" is about extensions, not elements. Second, your definition would make $\sqrt{2}$ "purely inseparable" over $\mathbb{Q}$. You need to specify that $F$ is of characteristic $p$. An element $a$ of an extension $E$ of $F$ is "inseparable" if its irreducible polynomial over $F$ is not separable, equivalently if $a\in F$ or $a\notin F$ and $a^{p^k}\in F$ for some $k\gt 0$. The extension is "purely inseparable" if and only if every $a\in E\setminus F$ is inseparable over $F$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is a root of $(x-a)^n\in K[x]$ and $n > 1$ then $a$ is also a root of the derivative $n (x-a)^{n-1}\in K[x]$.

So $(x-a)^n$ irreducible implies that $p|n$.

We get $(x-a)^n=(x^p-a^p)^{n/p}$.

Of course $(x-a^p)^{n/p}\in K[x]$ is irreducible as well.

And we can repeat the same argument, if $n/p>1$ then $p$ divides $n/p$...

To obtain that $n$ was a power of $p$.

Comment: looks good but how did you conclude that $p|n$ or put another way what will happen if $p$ doesn't divide  $n$?

Comment: @permutation_matrix If $p\nmid n$ then $n (x-a)^{n-1}$ is a smaller degree polynomial

Comment: oh, Earlier I didn't get the fact why $n(x-a)^{n-1}$ lie in $F$. But its the formal deriviative. So it will lie  over  $F$ and thus $n=0$. Right?

Comment: Yes $f=(x-a)^n\in F[x]$ implies $f'=n(x-a)^{n-1}\in F[x]$ if $p\nmid n$ then this contradicts the minimality of $(x-a)^n$. If $p|n$ then $f'=0$ and $f$ can be irreducible (try with $f=(x-t)^p\in \Bbb{F}_p(t^p)[x]$) @permutation_matrix

Comment: after concluding $n=pn_1$ after computing $p'(x)$ and assuming minimality of the polynomial. it is still unclear to me why after wrtting $p(x)=(x^p-a^p)^n_1$ we are able to conclude $p| n_1$. I tried computing the formal deriviative of $p(x)=(x^p-a^p)^n_1$ and it automatically turns out to be $0$ . so I cannot figure out why $p|n_1$

Comment: I think its because $(Y-a^p)^{n_1}$ will be the minimal polynomial of $a^p,$ and we repeat the procedure again. 

$(Y-a^p)^{n_1}$ is the minimal polynomial because it satisfies $a^p$ and if there is a lower degree $k<n_1$ polynomial then $a$ satisfies a polynomial of degree $pk<pn_1=n$ which contradicts the minimality of $p(x)$.

Comment: @permutation_matrix Yes need to repeat the same argument with $(Y-a^p)^{n_1}$ not $(x^p-a^p)^{n_1}$